# Is there a way to mimic browser flow SSO authentication in a asynchronous JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, oauth-2.0, electron

I'm working on a problem at the moment in which I need to authenticate a user of a desktop application with a oauth solution.

I know I could implement a solution where I redirect a browser on the authentication server, ask for creds then redirect to the resource to pull the data.

But, if I didn't want to actually use an external browser, is it possible to mimic the browser flow using just JS? In other words could I handle the redirects within JavaScript to finally achieve the token and next the data.

I haven't started the project just yet so this is kind of a feeling out question to see if the above is possible.

Just a small bit of info about the application. It's an Electron application. I have seen some examples for electron online but theses all use the external browser to achieve this.

I'm totally new to this type of work so any pointers in the right direction or help would be great.

And as I'm new to this type of work, apologies if it is a dumb question

Thanks for any help